# Iframe affecting history of main window when redirects

Tags: html, iframe

Hello i have a web application the has an iframe. and that site is usually redirecting to a certain webpage. and after redirect happened when i clicked back button of the browser The Iframe Redirection is added to my main window history. is there a way to prevent IFrame from adding a history entry whenever it redirects to a certain site.

I tried using adding an attribute to my iframe `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` but it seems that its not working is there a way to do it?.